# Listener for kafka partition change - Kafka node

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-node

I am currently working with Nodejs and Kafka, and I was looking for a way to detect changes in number of partitions in topics (currently using `kafka-node`)
Is there any API by which I can achieve this functionality?

I was thinking of calling `Client.loadMetadataForTopics()` every other hour or so to check the partitions numbers, but wanted to know if there were any other better methods available. Any suggestions or documentation links are also welcome. Thanks a lots!